# Reading float numbers line by line

Tags: c++

I have a file that contains float numbers stored line by line. Example:

```
1.5222
3.2444
4.0005
12.3331
```

I wanted my program to read the file line by line and store this numbers in a vector as strings and then convert them to long doubles. I wrote this piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
int j = 0;
cout.precision(16);
string s, weights;

cout << "You need to enter the filename of the file containing weights." << endl;
cout << "ENTER weights filename: ";
cin >> weights;
cout << endl;

ifstream weightsfile;
weightsfile.open(weights.c_str());

vector <string> weights_s;
vector <long double> weights_ld;

while(weightsfile >> j) // this loop reads weights from file
{
    getline (weightsfile, s);
    weights_s.push_back(s);
}

for(j = 0; j < weights_s.size(); j++) // this loop converts string data to long doubles and gives the output
    {
        weights_ld.push_back(strtold(weights_s[j].c_str(), NULL));
        cout << weights_s[j] << endl;
        cout << weights_ld[j] << endl;
    }

weightsfile.close();

return 0;
}
```

So what's the problem? The output is:

```
.5222
0.5222
.2444
0.2444
.0005
0.0005
.3331
0.3331
```

I suppose that my program skips the digits before decimal dots. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: `while(weightsfile >> j)` eats first zeros, as it basically says "read first integer from file

Comment: I've changed it to `while(weightsfile != NULL)` and it works fine. Thank you!

Comment: you need to change it to `while(getline(weightsfile, s)) weights_s.push_back(s);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while(weightsfile >> j)
```

reads an integer from the front of each line, your call to `getline` then reads the rest of the line.

```
while(getline(weightsfile, s))
{
    weights_s.push_back(s);
}
```

Would have the desired effect.

Do you actually need the list of strings? Could you just convert to doubles straight away (with some bonus error checking):

```
while(getline(weightsfile, s))
{
    size_t pos;
    weights_ld.push_back(std::stold(s, &pos));
    if (pos != s.size())
    {
       throw std::invalid_argument("invalid weight");
    }
}
```